# R if/else for loading RData or running code

Tags: r

I am interested in finding strategies in R to either run some code to produce the necessary output, then save, or if the RData file exists load it instead of running code.

By way of example:

```
if(!file.exists("saved.RData"){       
    savethis <- c(1,2,3,4)
    save(savethis, file="saved.RData")
}
if(file.exists("saved.RData"){
    load("saved.RData")
}
```

Any ideas are appreciated, I have had a good look around but not much on this. Also interested in what saving strategies are used, I typically save multiple objects into one file.RData, appropriately named of course!

Comment: Maybe `if( !("saved.RData" %in% list.files(getwd())) ) { savethis <- c(1,2,3,4) ; save(savethis, file="saved.RData") } else { load("saved.RData") }`

Comment: Thanks, think this is the sort of thing I am going to have to use, I thought there might be some slicker way but maybe not!

Comment: I suppose the only problem here is that you may have some initial data or code that generates `c(1, 2, 3, 4)` that could change and if it does you want to rebuild "saved.RData" even if it exists. Make and probably NextFlow take care of that for you. Another option, if you want to stay inside R is to put your code and datafiles in a git repository using `git2r` and then writing code like your example to also check which parts of your workflow have changed.

Comment: Yes, good points. I work interactively, and so edit in the saving of `RData` when I am satisfied with the results we have. For final full run, `NextFlow` will indeed handle changes to inputs, and therefore create new outputs owing to them. I also have functions held on `Github` as you specify. Yet to delve into `git2r`, probably required at this stage! Thanks for your input, really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) for this purpose. It is the standard tool for building something only if it needs building. It can even check if the precursors to your built .RData have changed and then rebuild it even if it exists.

First you need to install make; if you're on linux its probably already there. On Windows if you install [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/index.html) you will get it.

In your working directory you would have for example two Rscripts, lets call it foo.R that makes the dataset and plot.R that generates a plot and a Makefile (The file is named "Makefile"). The Makefile might look like this:

```
all: plot.pdf

my_data.Rda:foo.R
    Rscript foo.R

plot.pdf:my_data.Rda
    Rscript plot.R

clean:
    rm -f my_data.Rda
    rm -f plot.pdf
```

"foo.R" might look like this:

```
df <- cars
save(df, file = "my_data.Rda")
```

and "plot.R" could look like this:

```
load("my_data.Rda")

pdf("plot.pdf")
plot(df)
dev.off()
```

In the Makefile you have a number of rules that you define. First a rule 'all' that tells the software what to do by default and then a rule for each piece of the project you are building and what it is dependent on. In the above we have a rule that builds "plot.pdf" it is dependent on "my_data.Rda" therefore it will only run your "plot.R" script if the "plot.pdf" doesn't exist, but also that my_data.Rda must also exist and if it doesn't it will first be generated. You can try the following after you have make installed and generated these three file in one directory. Run the following command from a terminal:

```
make
```

This builds the "my_data.Rda" and then "plot.pdf". Now remove the "plot.pdf" file

```
rm plot.pdf
```

Then run Make again:

```
make
```

Notice that Make didn't need to rebuild the my_data.Rda file, so it didn't. Now remove both files and try again or run:

```
make clean
```

This is a rule that just brings you back to a clean slate to start over. If you are using Rstudio, there is even an option to build a project with a Makefile in the buildtools menu.

Comment: I use a workflow manager called [NextFlow](https://www.nextflow.io/), which does the same thing as `make` but is a little bit more user friendly. The issue is that I also like Jupyter notebook for interactivity and am keen to keep that element, particularly as the analyses generally are not defined but based on outcomes can go in multiple directions. If they were pre-defined, I would include as per your suggestion.